# DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE is not working after creating them with EncryptByPassPhrase

Tags: sql, encryption, sql-server-2014, password-encryption

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TempHashedValues(
HashedValues varbinary(200)
)
```

Now,  I am inserting encrypted values to it using, so that could be used later:

```
Insert into TempHashedValues values ( EncryptByPassPhrase('key', 'SecretEncoded' ))
```

Now when I am trying to decrypt them using same key:

```
Select TOP 1 DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key',HashedValues) from  TempHashedValues
```

I am just getting the binary value back , not the value I encrypted !!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated here http://sqlity.net/en/2530/decryptbypassphrase/
`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` returns the encrypted value as a `VARBINARY(8000)` data type. That data type, other than for example SQL_VARIANT does not carry any information about the originating data type. Therefore, the `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` also returns a `VARBINARY(8000)` value. 
You have to cast it :

```
Select TOP 1 (CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key',HashedValues) AS VARCHAR(8000))) from  TempHashedValues
```

Comment: some minor changes to the query to get it to work: Select TOP 1 (CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key',HashedValues) AS VARCHAR(8000))) from  TempHashedValues