# SQL Password decryption success but in C# Password when i run the project it can not able to get decrypt password

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have done encryption and decryption in SQL Server, but when I login password does not decrypt.
The below code is made for an encryption password field.

```
insert into login values('admin',ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SHA2_256','admin'))
```

And below code is made for a decryption password field.

```
select username, CONVERT(VARBINARY(50),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SHA2_256',pass))FROM LOGIN
```

But when I login that displays the password does not match in `C#`

And below is the C# code that does not work.

```
namespace login_Encrypt
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //static String decrypted;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uid = txtuser.Text;
        string pwd = txtpass.Text;
        string CPass = txtpass.Text.Trim();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SANJAY;Initial Catalog=prectic;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where username='" + txtuser.Text + "' AND pass='" + txtpass.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string t = ds.Rows[0]["pass"].ToString();
            string Dec = Decrypt(t.ToString(), "SHA2_256");
            //string NPass = (Dec + "MD5").ToLower();

            lblmess.Visible = true;
            lblmess.Text = "Matched";

        }
        else
        {
            lblmess.Text = "Sanjay";
        }
    }
        /*if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            user = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
            pass = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pass"].ToString();


                con.Close();
                Decrypt(pass);
                if(user==txtuser.Text && decrypted==txtpass.Text)
                {
                    lblmess.Text="success";
                }
          }*/


    public string Decrypt(string input, string key)
    {
        byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        tripleDES.Key = MD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
        //tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
        tripleDES.Clear();
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }

}
```

}

Does anyone have an idea how to decrypt the password at a run time? Please give me a Solution.

Comment: Does the SQL work to decrypt the password? Then show us the C# that doesn't work.

Comment: did you try this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314752/decryptbypassphrase-is-not-working-after-creating-them-with-encryptbypassphrase

Comment: Why are you only using 50 bytes?  Encryption keys can be larger.

Comment: I have tried more than 50 bytes but still not working.

Comment: I have added C# code.

Comment: Please include the table schema for `login`. I suspect the problem is that C# is en/decrypting UTF-16 encoded strings but your SQL is en/decrypting `varchar` instead.

Comment: username varchar(50),password varbinary(250)

Comment: Passwords should never be encrypted.  You should be salting and hashing them